# How to get rid of segmentation error I am getting from my given code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int count = 0;
struct node {
    int coef;
    int pow;
    struct node *link;
};
struct node *head = NULL;

void showoff() { 
    struct node *t1;
    t1 = head;

    while (t1 != NULL) {
        printf("|%d|%d|%x|--", t1->coef, t1->pow, t1->link);
        t1 = t1->link;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, i;
    struct node *temp, *t;
    t = head;
    printf("Number of nodes\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->coef = NULL;
        temp->pow = NULL;

        if (count == 0) {
            temp->link = head;
            head = temp;
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            temp->link = head->link;
            head->link = temp;
        }
        if (count > 1) {
            while (t->link != NULL) {
                t = t->link;
            }
            temp->link = t->link;
            t->link = temp;
        }
        count++;
    }
    showoff();
}
```

When I tried to debug this program it shows Program received signal `*SIGSEGV*,Segmentation fault`. I don't know what to do that's why I posted this question. Problem is with `while(t->link != NULL)`, Logically the code is right, so what's should I do to run this program properly? Like what changes should I do, please help me cause this made me mad whole day.

Comment: `coef` and `pow` are integer variable not pointer variable, `NULL` is `(void*)0`. It should be `temp->coef=0;` instead of `temp->coef=NULL;`

Comment: Recommend doing a search on "how to use a debugger gdb" and going through a tutorial.  It's the first step to never being mad all day again :)  You can also try pasting your code here and using their help system:  https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `t=head;` happens, `head` is `NULL`. `t` is never set to anything else, so when `while(t->link!=NULL)` happens, you're dereferencing `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting segs fault when `count > 1` because `t` is NULL. You set `t = head` at the beginning of main function, in for loop `head` is changed but `t` is not updated and it still contains NULL value, so set `t = head` in scope for `if (count>1)`:

```
if(count>1)
{
    t = head; // <------- new line
    while(t->link!=NULL)
    {
        t=t->link;
    }
    temp->link=t->link;
    t->link=temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks got the answer at last